# Amazon aurora MySQL Cluster size reduced drastically after major version upgrade

Tags: mysql

Amazon Aurora mysql db cluster I am currently working with had 7+ TB of data. After upgrading the major version from 5.6 to 5.7 the storage size has been reduced drastically from 7+ TB to 1+ TB. I noticed this with the daily automated snapshot. ( Note : The db cluster has encryption enabled at rest so there is no incremental snapshots).

I did compare the row counts of all the tables of all the databases assuming there could be any data loss. But row counts exactly Match. So I am clueless on the root cause.

I would really appreciate if someone can tell me what is going on here.

Comment: Most of the shrinkage probably came from a big `DELETE` that you did some time in the past.  That Delete was probably very slow.  See this for better options for next time:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/deletebig

Answer (score 1):

First of all: Could not find anything in the changelogs so far.

In general MySQL InnoDB for example does not release disk space after deleting data rows from the table. It keeps the space to reuse it later. You can free this space by calling the optimize table command. In case of an upgrade the optimize table could be part of the internal patching workflow to ensure the new logics apply.

FYI: here is explained how this optimization works in innodb
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30635603/what-does-table-does-not-support-optimize-doing-recreate-analyze-instead-me

For your purpose you can check the situation maybe on a backup in a testing environment.

Check table size:

```
SELECT table_schema as `Database`,table_name AS `Table`,round(((data_length + index_length) / 1024 / 1024), 2) `Size in MB`
FROM information_schema.TABLES
ORDER BY (data_length + index_length) DESC
LIMIT 5;
```

Optimization is available only when innodb_file_per_table is enabled.  Check your configuration like this (default is 'ON' in aurora afaik):

```
show variables like "innodb_file_per_table";
```

Run the optimizer:

```
OPTIMIZE table your_table_name;
```

Check the table size